# Integral curves in null hypersurfaces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields

> Let be $(M^{n+1},g)$ a spacetime (Lorentz manifold, connexe and time-oriented), $n\ge 2$, and $S\subset M$ a null hypersurface (codim $S=1$ and the restriction of $g$ to each tangent space $T_p S$ is degenerate).
>
> If $K$ is a null vector field of $S$, show that the integral curves of $K$ are null geodesics of $S$.

Everyone has a hint?

ERRATA: I would like understand why that problem is equivalent to show that
$$\nabla_K K=\lambda K,$$

where $\lambda\in C^\infty(S)$ is a smooth function. Cause, by $\nabla_K K=\lambda K$, if $\alpha$ is a integral curve of $K$, $\frac{d\alpha}{dt}=K(\alpha(t))$, then

$$\frac{D}{dt}\Big(\frac{d\alpha}{dt}\Big)=K(\alpha (t)),$$

and I don't understand why the right-hand side is zero.

Maybe I found something like that in the book *General Relativity: With Applications to Astrophysics*, By *Norbert Straumann*, p. 273.

[image]

It's sufficient to consider $\nabla \psi = K$, I think. But I don't understand the final line, in short the notation.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @JohnRennie, Thanks for the advise. I will add more informations about my question.

Comment: Adding more information will not make it on-topic. You have to show work and find the conceptual issue -- that's what the question should be.

Comment: In any case, the proof is given on page 684 of N. Straumann, *General Relativity*. 2013, Springer.

Comment: Thanks, @0celo7. I just needed look a little more the book.

Comment: @Irddo Not sure what "I just needed look a little more the book" means, but glad I could help?

Comment: @0celo7 I'm sorry, English is not my mother tongue. So, thanks so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31875/discussion-between-irddo-and-0celo7).